# ModelState.AddModelError but without the ErrorMessage (even default) - only highlight the field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Consider a simple Razor page:

```cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login)
    <br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
}
```

And this model:

```cs
public class LoginForm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please input the login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please input the password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when checking for the login in the controller I do something like this (because the login failure is not related to separately login or password):

```cs
if (loginFailed)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The specified login and password pair wasn't valid");
}
```

But how do I also mark both the Login and Password fields as invalid as well (`input-validation-error` CSS class) but without setting an error message?
When I do something like:

```cs
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(form.Login), string.Empty);
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(form.Password), string.Empty);
```

I end up with error messages saying

> The value 'somelogin' is invalid

and

> The value 'somepassword' is invalid

for both fields, in addition to the

> The specified login and password pair wasn't valid

Now, I can override this behaviour in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMvcOptions(mopt => mopt.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor(_ => string.Empty))
```

But that overrides everything globally, and I am loosing the message in case if the validation have nothing to do with this case.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Just remove both ValidationMessageFor and replace with one ValidationMessage( string.Empty )

Comment: I still need it for other validations (namely the Required validation)

Comment: Use blank space instead of string.Empty

Comment: That's one workaround I came across - either a space or a "\n". But this still seems to be more of a hack than an actual solution?...

Comment: Another hack would be to have if over the valuation message so that when model state is set to string empty you don't render the validator at all.

Comment: That would pretty much break client-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a really hacky workaround, which works surprisingly good though:
In the related Razor page I add the following code:

```cshtml
@{ 
    var isGeneralError = (ViewData.ModelState[string.Empty]?.Errors?.Any()).GetValueOrDefault(false);
}
```

And then for each input I want to highlight I just set the CSS class manually:

```cshtml
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { @class = isGeneralError ? HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName : null })
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = isGeneralError ? HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName : null })
```

This way I just keep the `ValidationMessageFor` ones unchanged aka in "validated" state, so they doesn't get any messages because I am not manipulating them with AddModelError at all.

I still think it is not a perfect solution, but it is still better than any other ones.

The fun part is that the client-side validation is kicking in as soon as you do anything with the fields, overriding this hack, which actually makes sense (at least, for me).